# switching adapters in rails and generated sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, multi-tenant

I'm writing a [multi-tenancy gem for rails](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment)

My tests right now establish connections for a particular adapter, run some tests, then repeat for subsequent db adapters.

My problem however is that when I call:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

with a different adapter, the sql generated from it is still in the form of the old adapter.  For instance, I run the mysql tests, then try to run postgresql tests.  I get an error:

```
Failure/Error: subject.create(database1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
  LINE 1: SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'Some ...
                         ^
  : SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'Some User 0' LIMIT 1
```

And it's obvious here that it's using the mysql backslash syntax, which isn't valid in postgresql.

So...  does anyone know how to establish a connection with a different adapter properly?  I've tried:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!
```

Neither of these fixed my tests.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses).each do |model|
     model.connection.clear_query_cache
  end
```

Comment: oh nice... so it turns out this is fixed in Rails 3.2 anyway.  I guess  I should make note of that.  If I have the chance (or the inclination) I might try this on my rails 3.0.x branch, but not sure when I might get to it.